# E-mail client to automatically handle attachments

Tags: sendemail, mail-server

I am looking for advice on where to start for this project:

My plan is to use my RPi as an server to handle files. I thought an easy way to do this to setup an e-mail client that watches for new e-mails. In this way, I am able to e-mail a file as attachment to an e-mail adress, the RPi then receives this file, runs some scripts on the attached file (based on the subject or message body) and then replies with the result from the scripts. The files are relatively small, max. 500kb.

**My question is: which email client is suited for this case?**

I already found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_email_clients#Text-based) list of text-based e-mail clients on Wikipedia, but it is not clear to me whether any of them meet my requirements:

- run on a RPi
- connect to standard POP3 or IMAP
- run scripts as new messages arrive

Instant update: [possibly related](http://onehourhacks.blogspot.nl/2013/01/extract-email-attachments-with-python.html).

Answer (score 1):

I found this [example](http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/HowTo/ScheduledEMailAttachmentDownloader) using fetchmail and procmail

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar idea, but I'm trying to decide if I want it to operate as its own mail server as well.

I found [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) to install postfix though if it helps.

Comment: I think you need to expand on your answer a little